# Is there a way to use the Readability script from off site

Tags: javascript, readability

https://www.readability.com/ is really amazing. I'm building a web app with content that I'd like to automatically run some resources through it and present the result in a lightbox.

There's a bookmarklet, but not much else. The API is dedicated to saving and updating things to a user's readability account, but not actually converting a page.

Is there a way run a site through the engine and return the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few libraries that have popped up to do this, which may be what you're looking for.

- [Readability Gem](https://github.com/sspinc/readability)
- [Boilerpipe](http://code.google.com/p/boilerpipe/)

I'd look into using something like that rather than trying to interact with [Readability](http://www.readability.com/) itself.